# C# If statement based on conditional Gridview cell color

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview, background-color

Apologies if this is trivial, but I am trying to switch from VB to C#. I'm trying to change the background color of a Datagridview cell conditional on the background color of another cell. For example,

> if row(0), cell(0) is "red", then make row(1), cell(1) "green".

In VB (which works) I use:

```
If GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red Then
GridView1.Rows(4).Cells(3).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
End If
```

But in C#:

```
if (GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red)
{
GridView1.Rows[4].Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
else
{
}
```

Instead I receive the **compile time error**:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.drawing.color' to 'bool'. I
>   understand that red is not true/false but I don't understand why it's
>   being interpreted as a boolean variable.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: change `=` to `==`: `if (GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Red)`

Comment: `==` for equality, `=` is for assignment.

Comment: I agree the == is missing because in C#, you cannot equalize just with one =, you can use for example BackColor.Equals()... instead too. I will suggest you to use this site from time to time when you're migrating C# to VB or vice versa. http://converter.telerik.com

Comment: Many thanks and best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

In VB, the single equals sign is used both for "Assignment"

```
Dim i as int = 10
```

And for "Comparison"

```
If GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red Then
```

In C#, a single equals sign is only used for "Assignment":

```
var i = 10;
```

If you want to do a "Comparison", you need two equals signs (`==`):

```
if (GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Red)
```

Comment: By the way. Anyone can vote (up or down) on a question or on an answer to a question.  It tends to indicate the worthiness of the question or answer (for example, I was just searching for something, I found someone who asked the same question I was interested in, and the answer was exactly what I was looking for - so I voted them both up).  The person who asks a question may find one of the answers is what he was looking for.  When that happens, the original poster can _Accept_ the answer.  I'm a little surprised 2 people voted this up, but the right way to say "thanks" is to accept it.